# php pdf not generate on online server

Tags: php

i have create 2 pages.

1. report.php
2. printForm.php

**report.php** is simple php page and **printform** is generate pdf page
when i generate pdf page not generate in online server and when i use local server so completely generate pdf file

`report.php` is filterig data page and that filtered data print on  pdf page
so i have used one hidden box and hidden box value are select query and transfer select query on `printForm.php` now i fetch data on pdf page but my code is correct so this page complete execute on local server and generate pdf but when i generate pdf on online server so that time all selected value is not print so plz
 plz help me

Comment: You should probably add the relevant code from the two pages.

Comment: MR. Jww Can you contact me via email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand...
If everything works fine on your local server, and does'nt perform as expected (Especially issues related to file creates, in your case PDF files) - check your permissions.

Most of the time you might not be having permissions to create a PDF file (if you are saving it first to a disk folder).

Comment: Yes, and that the conversion app is actually installed on the server.

Comment: MR. Veeru Can you contact me via email?

Comment: drop me an email at swamyveera@gmail.com - if i can help you, i will.